# converto-html breaks the table, tried with PSobject as input

Tags: powershell, azure

I get a strange output with Converto-HTML on Azure function for the following:
I am trying to build a HTML and pipe it to Converto-HTML and send email with style. The output is table with header column with value '*' and data row column value as 146 or 189 or sort.

**Script** :

```
 $applicationtable1 = "< table>< th>Application Name< /th>< th>Requested By< /th>< th>Requested Date< /th>< /tr>"
 $applicationtable1 += "< tr>< td> hi < /td>< td> hi < /td> < td> hi < /td>< /tr> < /table>"
$applicationtable1
$Body = New-Object PSObject 
$Body | Get-Member #validating proper ps object
 $Body = $applicationtable1

 $htmlBody = $Body | ConvertTo-HTML | out-string

 write-host $htmlBody
```

**Output**

*

---

146

**Local Output**

```
PS C:\Users\292883> $Body = New-Object PSObject

PS C:\Users\292883> $Body = $applicationtable1

PS C:\Users\292883> $htmlBody = $Body | ConvertTo-HTML | out-string

PS C:\Users\292883> write-host $htmlBody
```

I tried to create a PS object and then pipe it as well but it appears both gets me same output.

Also, tried instead of PSObject, using PSCustomObject as below. it appears working but still output got a merged header table row.

```
$results = @()
$applicationtable1 = "< table>< tr>Application Name< /tr>< tr>Requested By< /tr>< tr>Requested Date< /tr>< /tr>"
$applicationtable1 += "< tr>< td> hi < /td>< td> hi < /td> < td> hi < /td>< /tr> < /table>"


$item = New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
      'html' = $applicationtable1

    }
 $results = $item | ConvertTo-HTML | out-string
```

**Output Fragment which still appears even if I dont have header row **

> < table >
>   < colgroup >< col/ >
>   < tr >< th > *  < / th >< / tr >

Comment: I completed my mail app with text format since was not able to resolve this challenge but still would like to have a html formatted mail implemented. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConvertTo-Html takes an object and provides you with an HTML representation of that. What you're creating is going to generate an HTML table with a single column with the title "Html". All content of that table is subject to HTML encoding (< will become < and so on).

If you wish to use ConvertTo-Html you must feed it an Object.

```
$item = [PSCustomObject]@{
    'Application Name' = 'hi'
    'Requested By'     = 'hi'
    'Requested Date'   = 'hi'
}
$item | ConvertTo-HTML | out-string
```

You may include PreContent and PostContent in raw HTML using their respective parameters. Similarly you may include CSS styles and so on using the Head parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I get your suggestion and this is working.

Comment: Adding to your advice, hoping someone might find it useful :   `$objects = @()
$objects += New-Object -Type PSObject -Prop @{'FName'='Hari';'LName'='Bala'}
$objects += New-Object -Type PSObject -Prop @{'FName'='cute';'LName'='geek'}
$objects += New-Object -Type PSObject -Prop @{'FName'='cool';'LName'='geek'}
$objects | ConvertTo-HTML -As Table -Fragment | Out-String`

Comment: In the case of multiple table, the fragment merge with -PostContent do not appear to give me a complete HTML page instead object. Example code :  $item = [PSCustomObject]@{ 'Application Name' = 'hi'
    'Requested By'     = 'hi'
    'Requested Date'   = 'hi'
}
$item | ConvertTo-HTML -AS Table -Fragment | out-string
$item1 = [PSCustomObject]@{
    'Application Name' = 'hi'
    'Requested By'     = 'hi'
    'Requested Date'   = 'hi'
}
$item1 | ConvertTo-HTML -AS Table -Fragment | out-string
ConvertTo-Html -PostContent $item, $item1 | Out-String

Comment: The above sample snippet gives me < b ody >
< table> 
< / table>
@{Application Name=hi; Requested By=hi; Requested Date=hi}
@{Application Name=hi; Requested By=hi; Requested Date=hi}
< / body>

Comment: You're missing some variable assignments. At the point you're adding $item and $item1 as the PostContent they're still PSObject.

Comment: Make each of those similar to this: `$item = $item | ConvertTo-HTML -AS Table -Fragment | out-string`. That replaces the value in $item with the HTML string generated by ConvertTo-Html for you to inject into your document.

Comment: Thank you, Sir! your pointer worked. My bad, missed this check.